# Is it possible to change HTML title with SwashBuckle and Swagger UI

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

We have many services, which use SwashBuckle / Swagger UI to expose REST methods.

It can often be annoying when you have several of them open in tabs in a browser that you cannot immdiately see the service name from the tabs. At least not without switching to that tab

Is it possible to change the HTML title from SwashBuckle?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, Simply change document title

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(option => 
{ 
    ...
    option.DocumentTitle = "Your Title"; 
    ...
});
```